# Array Initialization: Is this wrong?

Tags: java, arrays

I am pretty confused about array initialization.finds it quite complex task.

```
public int[] make2(int[] a, int[] b) {
  int[] make2=new int[2];
  if(a.length==2 )
  {
  make2={a[0],a[1]};
  }

  return make2;
}
```

Is it wrong? can anyone explain the ways to initialize a array without taking a loop.

Update for this

Here is the updated code.
But can you please let me know the version which will help me to avoid creating a extra array which is of no use.When i do not use it and directly returns the make 2 at end,the compiler complains that make2 cannot be resolved

```
public int[] make2(int[] a, int[] b) {
 int[] large=new int[3];
  if(a.length>=2 )
  {
 int[] make2={a[0],a[1]};
 return make2;
  }
  else if(a.length==1)
  {
 int[] make2={a[0],b[0]};
 return make2;
  }
  else if(a.length==0)
  {
 int[] make2={b[0],b[1]};
 return make2;
  }
return large;
}
```

Comment: That code will not compile, why do not try it yourself?

Comment: You're certainly making it quite complex. You're not even using the second parameter of your method.

Comment: That was not complete code only a section.Please check the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply:

```
int make2[] = new int[]{a[0], a[1]};
```

Comment: Downvoter, I want to learn from my mistakes. **Please explain**.

Answer (score 1):

int[] make2 = new int[] { a[0], a[1] };

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3, 4,5,6,7};
```

or

```
    int[] a = {1,2};
    int[] b={2,3};
    int[] aa={a[0], b[1]};
```